# Como muestro y oculto cuando paso el mouse sobre una etiqueta?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo el siguiente elemento de etiquetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera lograr poder que se vea de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando pase el cursor (mouse) por una de las etiquetas se muestre de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los elementos dentro del contenedor se utilizan para mostrar etiquetas con contenido relacionado en la página.

```css
.tags{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
}
.tag1 {
    background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
  }
  .tag2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
  }
  .tag3 {
    background-color: rgb(248, 75, 7);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag1">
            Consulta con auditoria
        </div>
        <div class="tag2">
            En cotizacion
        </div>
        <div class="tag3">
            Espera de documentación
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para la punta de flecha puedes usar `clip-path` aquí un [generador](https://unused-css.com/tools/clip-path-generator), luego el resto es dejar un `width` pequeño y al hacer hover aumentarlo

```css
.tags{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
}

.verde {
    background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
}
.amarillo {
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
}
.rojo {
    background-color: rgb(248, 75, 7);
}
  
.tags div{
   position: relative;
   height:33px;
   color:black;
   padding-right:20px;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:16px;
   display:flex;
   text-align: left;
   align-items: center;
   clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 74% 0%, 85.5% 50%, 74% 100%, 0% 100%);
   white-space: nowrap;
   transition: width 0.6s;
}
   
.tags div:before{
   content:'  ';
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left:30px;
}

.tags div:hover{
   width:240px;;

}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div class="verde">
      Consulta con auditoria
  </div>
  <div class="amarillo">
      En cotizacion
  </div>
  <div class="rojo">
      Espera de documentación
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me gusto tu respuesta +1.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si entendí bien lo que necesitas, pero te propongo esta opción, añadiendo a cada clase lo siguiente (para que el texto no se salga del div y realice la animación):

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
transition: width 0.75s
```

Y luego añadiendo `hover` a esas mismas clases podrías obtener lo que creo necesitas.

```css
.tags{
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
}
.tag1 {
    background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
    width: 25%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: width 0.75s
  }
  .tag2 {
    background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
    width: 25%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: width 0.75s
  }
  .tag3 {
    background-color: rgb(248, 75, 7);
    width: 25%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    transition: width 0.75s
  }
  
.tag1:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
.tag2:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
.tag3:hover {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tags">
        <div class="tag1">
            Consulta con auditoria
        </div>
        <div class="tag2">
            En cotizacion
        </div>
        <div class="tag3">
            Espera de documentación
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución sería encerrar en etiquetas `<span>` a tus textos para luego darles un `padding` y tengan un espacio a la izquierda y derecha:

```
.tags div span {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Hacemos esto debido a que el ancho de cada `tag` medirá `20px`, y como estamos empujando a la izquierda a cada texto (que son los `<span>`), se verá solo el espacio vacío en el recuadro:

```
.tags div {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Aquí indico que cada `tag` tendrá un ancho de `20px`, el texto estará alineado al centro, el contenido fuera del contenedor permanecerá oculto y no hacemos un salto de línea con `nowrap`.

```css
.tags {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
}

.tag1 {
  background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
}

.tag2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
}

.tag3 {
  background-color: rgb(248, 75, 7);
}

.tags div span {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.tags div {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div class="tag1">
    <span>Consulta con auditoria</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tag2">
    <span>En cotizacion</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tag3">
    <span>Espera de documentación</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y para lograr el efecto de la animación, tendríamos que usar la pseudo-clase [**`:hover`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), indicando que al pasar el mouse encima, su ancho medirá `250px` y que el contenido de adentro será visible:

```
.tags div:hover {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.tags {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
}

.tag1 {
  background-color: rgb(145, 255, 0);
}

.tag2 {
  background-color: rgb(255, 196, 0);
}

.tag3 {
  background-color: rgb(248, 75, 7);
}

.tags div span {
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.tags div {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
}

.tags div:hover {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div class="tag1">
    <span>Consulta con auditoria</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tag2">
    <span>En cotizacion</span>
  </div>
  <div class="tag3">
    <span>Espera de documentación</span>
  </div>
</div>
```